# support direct print in ionic cordova app without user interaction

Tags: angular, cordova, printing, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic5

I have a mobile app which is created for IOS and Android. it's built with Ionic 5 and Cordova (latest).

My app requires printing to pos terminal which is a thermal printer. today, if the user aims to print, he needs to do two clicks to bypass the printdialog.

We are looking for a better way to do that, without the user interaction. a global way that can work with many printer types.

Any one have any idea on that? looking forward to get some insights